# With or without the inclusion guards in C headers, it still works. What is it for then?

Tags: c, header, include, guard, inclusion

I tried compiling with or without the inclusion guards in C headers and made sure that multiple c files includes the same header. It would result to redeclaration and it is allowed. What does it for then?

Answer (score 3):

You prevent circular inclusion:

### Example

```
/** file A.h */
#include "B.h"
```

```
/** file B.h */
#include "A.h"
```

What will happen if you include either "A.h" or "B.h"? Your pre-processor will try to include the other file, which will include the other file, which will include the other file, …

Guards make sure that you won't include the file several times.

Comment: Would it cause a compiler error if that's the case? Because I just tried it in dev cpp and it still did compile.